# jQuery load header/footer in multiple webpages not working / path error

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, backend

I am making a website in VScode and I want to include header and footer in every page.
I have created `header.html` and `footer.html` and I am using folowing jQuery to load the the templates.

```
$(function(){
    $("#header").load("header.html");
    $("#footer").load("footer.html");
})
```

the issue is that the header is loading in pages located at the root of folder but if I use the function anywhere down the directory, it fails to load `header.html`

I have made a `header.js` which contains the above function and I link it in every page.
Is there any way to resolve this issue, otherwise I'll have to use `../` in `.load()` to move up the directory in every page which kind of fails the meaning the meaning of reusabilty.
Using `../`will mean I cannot link the same .js in every page.

I have zero knowledge of backend, and I am trying to avoid PHP because I am thinking to learning javascript once I finish the frontend part.
JS is highly encouraged for the solution, however other ways are also welcomed.

Comment: When the `header.html` is in the root of your website you can use `$("#header").load("/header.html");` to always load it from any directory. The slash indicates that it should start at the root. Have a look at the [URL path syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/Web_mechanics/What_is_a_URL#path_to_resource), you just left out too much.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware it worker. Thank you.  One Question-- Is using `/` a standard way of doing such thing or will I face any issues during hosting.  If yes, then I'll use same method for images also

Comment: Yes, a slash, at the start of a path, is a standard method of referring to the root of a website. This is only true for an URL, used in HTML or Javascript, in a web page.

Comment: How is  `php` related?

Comment: @brombeer I'm using `.load()` for making dynamic pages. Standard practice for dynamic webpages is using server side scripting.  It is very easy inject code using PHP, but for other scripting laguages you'll not find a definitive answer.  My preferance pure javascript,  however if  any other solution including use of PHP was welcomed.  If anyone can provide the injection solution with PHP I don't mind

Answer (score 0):

Use a web path. For instance take the example bellow pretending the host name is 'localhost':

```
-- project folder
  -- index.html
  -- js (folder)
    -- header.html
    -- footer.html
```

- You need only to navigate through the url:

> localhost/js/header.html

- Using js to dynamically creating the path:

> window.location.href + 'js/header.html';